# Why are my service workers not working offline

Tags: service-worker

Everything seems to be right and the files are being cached but it just doesn't work offline. Am I missing something obvious?

the cache.addAll did not want to work with my const FILES_TO_CACHE but do work when I put them in directly. Thus the repeated code.

Here is my service worker file:

```
const FILES_TO_CACHE = [
  "/",
  "/index.html",
  "/style.css",
  "/db.js",
  "/index.js",
  "/manifest.webmanifest"
];

const CACHE_NAME = "static-cache-v2";
const DATA_CACHE_NAME = "data-cache-v1";

// install
self.addEventListener("install", function(evt) {
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(cache => {
      console.log("Your files were pre-cached successfully!");
      return cache.addAll([
        "/",
        "/index.html",
        "/style.css",
        "/db.js",
        "/index.js",
        "/manifest.webmanifest"
      ]);
    })
  );

  self.skipWaiting();
});

// activate
self.addEventListener("activate", function(evt) {
  console.log("activated");
  evt.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(keyList => {
      return Promise.all(
        keyList.map(key => {
          if (key !== CACHE_NAME && key !== DATA_CACHE_NAME) {
            console.log("Removing old cache data", key);
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        })
      ).catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
  );

  self.clients.claim();
});

// fetch
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(evt) {
  console.log("fetched", evt.request.url);

  if (evt.request.url.includes("/api/")) {
    evt.respondWith(
      caches
        .open(FILES_TO_CACHE)
        .then(cache => {
          return fetch(evt.request)
            .then(response => {
              // If the response was good, clone it and store it in the cache.
              if (response.status === 200) {
                cache.put(evt.request.url, response.clone());
              }

              return response;
            })
            .catch(err => {
              // Network request failed, try to get it from the cache.
              return cache.match(evt.request);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    );

    return;
  }
});
```

link in html:

```
<script>
      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service-worker.js").then(function() {
          console.log("Service Worker Registered");
        });
      }
    </script>
```

I also have my manifest linked in the HTML file.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the last line of code here:

```
// fetch
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(evt) {
  console.log("fetched", evt.request.url);

  if (evt.request.url.includes("/api/")) {
```

you see that there's a very simple mistake – your Service Worker is *ONLY* responding to requests that start with "/api/". If they don't, the SW doesn't touch them. Thus only "/api/" calls work offline (which doesn't make any sense :-), apis being mostly dynamic, right?).

(It is possible that there's another bug in the code of course, but this is a good point to start making changes.)

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to a "/" earlier and it did not work but I must have had something else wrong because now it works like a charm!!